# Equality of distributions of two bounded random variables $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two bounded random variables. Then I want to show:

> $\forall n \in \Bbb N$ it holds that $\Bbb E(X^n)=\Bbb E(Y^n)$ $\Rightarrow$ X and Y have the same distribution.

I want to argue with characteristic functions but the only thing I can imagine to be helpful here, is the identity $\frac {d^r}{dt^r} \phi(0)=i^r\Bbb E(X^r)$. However I can´t see how to proof this statement. I would be very thankful for any help!

Comment: An option is to use Bolzano-Weierstrass to show that $E(f(X))=E(f(Y))$ for every continuous function $f$.

Comment: @Did Sorry but this is a bit to fast for me :) and how would BW led to characteristic functions ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to argue with characteristic functions, show that the CF of a bounded random variable has a power series expansion with infinite radius of convergence. That is, show that the expansion
$$\phi(t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty i^nt^n{E(X^n)\over n!}$$
is valid for all $t$. (Hint: Use the root test, with an appropriate bound on $E(X^n)$.)

Comment: Hm ok then I could conclude that X and Y have the same characteristic function and therefore they must have the same distribution.

Comment: @user326049 Yep!

Comment: thank you I will try this, maybe this was also the way that "Did" suggested in his comment